# How can I download and easily install 64-bit Vim for Windows?

Tags: microsoft-windows, installing

I'm using Windows 10.

I want to view a 3.8 GB log file. I'd rather use Vim, not [less(1)](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Less_(Unix)).

I looked at [this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/6097/), but it really only tells me how to download 64-bit Vim, not how to install it. (TuxProject's "complete-x64.exe" file is a self-extracting archive, not an installer.)

I want a simple way to install a full Vim on Windows, including an "Edit with Vim" context-menu item in Windows Explorer.

What should I do?

Comment: Not sure if having two duplicate questions is useful here, since it's basically just asking the same thing. The "download" in the title refers to "download and install". I just edited it to be "install". I'll move your answer to that other question. Thanks!