# How do you install 64-bit version of vim 8.2 from gvim82.exe?

Tags: installing

The download page clearly states that the gvim82.exe installer has an option to choose which version of vim to install, a 32- or a 64-bit. I cannot find this option. The installed vim is 32-bit, while I need a 64-bit.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: the download page mentions the [vim-win32-installer repository](http://github.com/vim/vim-win32-installer/), which includes 32bit and 64 bit binaries.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt I found a related link and added to my answer but people should keep in mind that those are nightly builds and, by definition, not as stable as official releases.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it clearly states what you say it does, actually. It says...

> [this installer] includes GUI and console versions, for 32 bit and 64 bit systems.

That means the GUI and console versions will work on 64-bit systems. It doesn't mean the executable is 64-bit.

If you continue reading...

> There are *also* 64bit versions which only run on 64 bit MS-Windows and use a lot more memory, but is compatible with 64 bit plugins."

(My emphasis on the "also".)

They don't recommend using the 64-bit version so they don't provide ready access to it. (It also used to say that "it wasn't used much and maintenance stopped" but that was removed at some point.)

I use the 32-bit version, personally, despite being what you could call an "advanced" user. I recommend doing likewise unless you are using plugins available only in 64-bit. (This is not particularly common.)

Generally speaking, for small footprint programs there's not all that much of an advantage to compiling to 64-bit. On 64-bit Windows, the `c:\program files (x86)` folder contains installed 32-bit executable apps and you'll notice there are a lot of them. Unless you need to address very large amounts of memory or have some other, less common need, there's not much to be gained with a 64-bit runtime. There may even be downsides to it such as consumption of more memory versus the 32-bit version (as mentioned by Vim's download page).

Now if you have some unavoidable compatibility issue (or you weren't convinced by any of the above) then head over to [How can I install 64-bit Vim on Windows?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/6097/how-can-i-install-64-bit-vim-on-windows) for guidance. Alternatively, if you don't mind using a possibly less stable version of Vim you can find 64-bit Vim among the [official nightly builds](https://github.com/vim/vim-win32-installer/releases).

Comment: « Address very large amounts of memory »—perhaps there’s a large file in the mix? :)

Comment: Sure, if you're in the habit of opening 4+ GB files on a regular basis by all means go with 64-bit. :P  But seriously, I've never hit this limit in all my years of vimming on windows. If you're opening multi-gig files with a text editor you're doing it wrong.

Comment: if you use python based plugins and you have python for x64 installed, vim have to be x64 too

Comment: @MaximKim Yes. Thus the reference to "unavoidable compatibility issue(s)". But that doesn't necessarily mean that there is only a 64-bit version of the plugin...just that you'd rather not change your Python installation (or use `pyenv` or whatever those tools are called.)

Comment: This is not really a separate answer, just pointing out a useful one under the linked [Windows 64-bit thread](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/6097/how-can-i-install-64-bit-vim-on-windows) in B Layer's answer. I use Chocolatey to install Vim-Tux (64-bit Windows version) along with 64-bit Python and other packages related to my Vim setup. See steps here: https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/11826/28874